# HOWTO: Apache index page banner?

Tags: apache-2.2, mirror, directoryindex

I'd like Apache index pages to show my company banner w/ link to homepage on top.

Instead of:

```
Index of /pub/something
```

to show

```
[Company Banner]
Index of /pub/something
```

I added these lines to `.htaccess`:

```
HeaderName HEADER.html 
ReadmeName README.html
```

and edited `HEADER.html` to include banner with link but that banner is only shown to `/pub` and not `/pub/dir` pages.

THis is what i currently have in .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
HeaderName HEADER.html
ReadmeName README.html
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html?

Comment: I added these lines to .htaccess:

`HeaderName HEADER.html
ReadmeName README.html`

and edited HEADER.html to include banner with link but that banner is only shown to /pub and not /pub/dir pages. Any suggestion re this?

Comment: In the future, please add such information via an edit to the question, not a comment. That's what the `edit` button is for :)

Comment: Did you by any chance add those lines within a <Directory> context? It'd probably be easier to help you if you could post the whole .htaccess file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've got it.

You're using a relative path to your HEADER.html and your Readme.html. That makes Apache look for the files within whatever directory you're in.

Instead, the lines should (presumably) read something like this:

```
HeaderName /pub/HEADER.html
ReadmeName /pub/README.html
```

(of course, replace "pub" with whatever directory the files are actually in!)

Comment: Note to others: The directory is the URL from the browser's point of view, not from the server's operating system's POV.